# having a hard time displaying data in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my code for loading a table. The variable `name` used, and `id` for the table in HTML is correct but `file11` for `innnerHTML`, that stores all `td` and `tr` tags, and data from firebase isn't stored and when printed in the console it shows nothing.

[image: PRINTSCREEN OF CONSOLE].

```
function initializer(){
    refReview=firebase.database().ref().child("review");
    tableBody = document.getElementById("table_body");
    loadTables();   
}

function loadTables(){
    refReview.on("value", function(snap){
        var data = snap.val();
        var file11 = "";

        for(var key in data){
            console.log("keys retrieved",data[key].revieweeID);
            var idOfReviewee = data[key].revieweeID;

            getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(idOfReviewee);
            getDataToUsers.once("value",function(snap){
                var fnLn =snap.val();
                    console.log(fnLn.firstname);
                    file11 += "<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + fnLn.firstname + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + fnLn.lastname + "</td>" +
                              "</tr>";
            });

            console.log("data of table file11:",file11);

        }//end of for loop

        tableBody.innerHTML = file11;

    });
}       //end table function
```

But if this is the structure of the code, `file11`, which is the `innerHTML` has data inside and table is structured well. But I want to get data from a certain reviewer from other group in firebase database. Since till retrieve their names which is stored in different group and is reference according to `revieweeID`.

```
function loadTables(){
    refReview.on("value", function(snap){
        var data = snap.val();
        var file11 = "";

        for(var key in data){
            console.log("keys retrieved",data[key].revieweeID);
            var idOfReviewee = data[key].revieweeID;

            getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(idOfReviewee);
            getDataToUsers.once("value",function(snap){
                var fnLn =snap.val();
                    console.log(fnLn.firstname);
            });

            file11 += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].content + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].content + "</td>" +


                      "</tr>";

            console.log("data of table file11:",file11);

        }//end of for loop

        tableBody.innerHTML = file11;

    });
}       //end table function
```

Comment: why is it that the console is structured like that? 
it must be 
key retrieved ,
first name,
data of table file 11

Comment: Can you see the data at this line ? -> `var data = snap.val();`

Comment: yes i can.

problem solved! .ref method returns asynchronous and in the meantime the code below is executed first because it deosnt wait